# CSS, getting a Div to Expand the height of the page

Tags: css, reactjs, redux

I am doing my first React-Redux project and I am working on styling.

The issue I am having is with background colors.

If I set a background color on a div containing the main content of a page, the bottom of the page is left white.

My solution was to set a default background color in my reset file, on the body and html. This fixed the problem.

However, I want to have different background colors/images on different pages and if I have the body and html set to a default color that color will be the color below the div on any page.

Any help would be appreciated. This again is using React and Redux, I am brand new to this material and from my understanding , all the components will be nested under a parent element (body in my case) so changing that will affect every page. That said is there a way to make a div fill all the space between a header and eventually footer element?

Comment: Use scripting to change it via page events or use CSS to set it via URL (filepath).

Comment: can you share your code snippet, shall be easy to answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your main content element needs to be 100% of the height of the page, you can use

```
height:100vh;
```

This will give the element a height which is equal to 100% of the view height. This is supported in all current browsers except opera mini.

Beware of margins or padding on parent elements as these could make your container overflow the page slightly - see how i have dealt with the margin on the body in [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeyYXL)